# make a condition in select an output based on agent's stay time

Tags: anylogic

How to make a condition in which the agent would choose a variant after a certain time in the simulation? After like 60 minutes?

I'm talking about exiting the loop if the agent exceeds a given time or number of laps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp86k.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a condition in which the agent would choose a variant after a certain time in the simulation? After like 60 minutes

In your `SelectOutput` condition, simply use `time() > 60*minute()`. All agents will  stay in the loop for the first 60 mins of your simulation, then always leave.

> I'm talking about exiting the loop if the agent exceeds a given time or number of laps.

This is an entirely different problem and can be achieved as follows:

1. In your agent type, add a variable `v_Counter` of type `int`.
2. In your `Delay` block "on enter", add to that variable using `agent.v_Counter++;`
3. In your `SelectOutput` block, use the condition `agent.v_Counter >= 123`

This will make agents stay in the loop 123 times, then they will exit it